# Self-Join/Case Statement/Cross or Outer apply/Pivot Confusion

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have created a sqlfiddle for problem I am facing. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fea87/2
I am not sure the best way to code to generate the desired result below. Or, you can suggest on a better way to display the result. Could someone please help? From Questionnaire table, we need to pick the first Response of the duplicate query. I will post my code once I figure out something.

```
CREATE TABLE Data
    ([CustomerID] int, [Name] varchar(50))
;  
INSERT INTO Data
    ([CustomerID], [Name])
VALUES
    (1001, 'Harvey'),
    (2001, 'Mike'),
    (3001, 'Dana')
;
CREATE TABLE Questionnaire
    ([CustomerID] int, [Review] varchar(50),[Response] varchar(50))
;  
INSERT INTO Questionnaire
    ([CustomerID], [Review],[Response])
VALUES
    (1001,'Query1','79'),
    (1001,'Query2','80'),
    (1001,'Query3' ,'90'),
    (1001,'Query1' ,'95'),
    (1001,'Query2' ,'98'),
    (1001,'Query3' ,'60'),
    (2001,'Query1','81'),
    (2001,'Query2','70'),
    (2001,'Query3' ,'61'),
    (2001,'Query1' ,'65'),
    (2001,'Query2' ,'70'),
    (2001,'Query3' ,'52')
;
CREATE TABLE Amenities
    ([CustomerID] int, [Utility] varchar(50))
;  
INSERT INTO Amenities
    ([CustomerID], [Utility])
VALUES
    (1001, 'Breakfast'),
    (1001, 'Lunch'),
    (1001, 'Gym');
```

Desired Result:

```
CustomerID   Query1   Query2   Query3   Utility
1001         79       80       90       Breakfast
1001         79       80       90       Lunch
1001         79       80       90       Gym
2001         81       70       61       Null
3001         Null     Null     Null     Null
```

This code worked for me but if you can think of anything simpler than this, please let me know.

```
select a.CustomerID,ab.Response,cd.Response,ef.Response,d.Utility
from Data a
outer apply (select top 1 b.Response
             from Questionnaire b
             where a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
             and b.Review='Query1') as ab

outer apply (select top 1 c.Response
             from Questionnaire c
             where a.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
             and c.Review='Query2') as cd

outer apply (select top 1 d.Response
             from Questionnaire d
             where a.CustomerID=d.CustomerID
             and d.Review='Query3') as ef
left join Amenities d
on a.CustomerID=d.CustomerID
```

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2012, *and* SQL Server 2014?  Please tag your question appropriately.  I am removing these tags and replacing them with sql-server.

Comment: Does Questionnaire have an ID column in your real version that indicates the order of entry?

Comment: Gordon! I edited to sql-server-2012.

Comment: KimvdLinde! Yes, Questionnaire table has CustomerID column so we can join using CustomerID.

Comment: I saw that, what I mean is a unique index that is unique. That would essentially help you order the records with a similar customer ID and you can then very easy pick up the first one using the ROW_NUMBER function.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. No, there is no unique index id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do is change the questionnaire table to:

```
CREATE TABLE Questionnaire( QuestionnaireID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
                                              NOT NULL,
                           CustomerID     INT NULL,
                           Review         VARCHAR(50) NULL,
                           Response       VARCHAR(50) NULL )
ON [PRIMARY];
```

Then you can get the code out with:

```
WITH x
         AS ( SELECT CustomerID,
                     Query1,
                     Query2,
                     Query3
              FROM( 
                    SELECT CustomerID,
                           Review,
                           Response,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID,
                                                          Review 
                                                       ORDER BY QuestionnaireID) AS rowID
                    FROM Questionnaire ) AS sourceTable 
                PIVOT( MAX(Response) FOR Review IN( Query1,
                                                        Query2,
                                                        Query3 )) AS pivotTable
              WHERE rowid = 1 )
     SELECT d.CustomerID,
            Query1,
            Query2,
            Query3,
            a.Utility
     FROM x
          LEFT JOIN Amenities a ON x.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
          RIGHT JOIN Data d ON x.CustomerID = d.CustomerID;
```

It is generally good practice to have an unique index in your table as it facilitates a lot of things.

This gives me:

```
CustomerID  Query1  Query2  Query3  Utility
1001    79  80  90  Breakfast
1001    79  80  90  Lunch
1001    79  80  90  Gym
2001    81  70  61  NULL
3001    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I have view only rights on the server. I am going for a religious ceremony but will update my trial code by tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: It won't be possible then as the select query with no order by does not retrieve the rows in any particular order. And you do not have something to rank the first from the second, and hence you do not know what order the database gives them back to you.

Comment: I will try several self join with cross apply in which we can do select top 1.

Comment: You can do that, but the problem is that the order in which the records are extracted from the database is not guaranteed. Therefore, you will get one random row as your top 1 and not the first inserted one.

Comment: There will be no ordering issue. I have updated my code in my original post and it works. Thanks for your concern and I will mark your code as an answer though.